# How to check that customer is logged in on frontend in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2, frontend

How to check that customer is logged in? 
In authentication-popup.js I found following code:

```
define([..., 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',...], 
    function(..., customerData, ...) {
        return Component.extend({
            ...
            /** Is login form enabled for current customer */
            isActive: function () {
                var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                return customer() == false;
            },
        });
    }
);
```

I copied it to my module, but it seems like isn't works, it still returns false after login.

Any ideas?

Env:
- Magento 2.1.1
- Magento/blank theme

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Magento 2.1.1 has an issue when full page cache is disabled - customer data isn't updating after success login. [Details](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/6473)

Also sometimes customer data can be still not loaded (waiting for response), so in order to catch this case I prepared following code:

```
/**
 * This file will check that customer is logged in
 */
define(
    ['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'],
    function ($, customerData) {
        'use strict';

        var getCustomerInfo = function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');

            return customer();
        };

        var isLoggedIn = function (customerInfo) {
            customerInfo = customerInfo || getCustomerInfo();

            return customerInfo && customerInfo.firstname;
        };

        return function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var customerInfo = getCustomerInfo();

            if (customerInfo && customerInfo.data_id) {
                deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn(customerInfo));
            } else {
                customerData.reload(['customer'], false)
                    .done(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn());
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
            }

            return deferred;
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: So, it is a Magento bug and you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, this issue reproducing only when full page cache is disabled.

Comment: With this module you cannot handle failed conditions correctly, e.g.: `getLoggedInStatus().then(function(sFirstName) { console.log(sFirstName ? 'Logged in' : 'Not logged in'); }).fail(function() { console.log('Failed to get customer data'); });`. Fix: change `deferred.fail()` to `deferred.reject()`.

Comment: I updated my post, thank you for getting it!

Comment: how does 'customerData' get injected into that function call?

Comment: OK, I tried implementing this and it's dying in 'getFromServer' in customer-data.js  at the return when it's trying to reference options.sectionLoadUrl because options is undefined.

Comment: facing the same issue as @Scott said

Comment: @Gery I added a solution that managed to work for me using the requirejs mechanisms to load it. (if you need the syntax for that, let me know)

Answer (score 7):

```
define(['Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], 
    function(customer) {
        return Component.extend({
            someMethod: function () {
                if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                   //do smth
                } else {
                   //do smth
                }
            },
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to:

*vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/Customer.php*

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        if (!$this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
            return [];
        }
        $customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
        return [
            'fullname' => $this->customerViewHelper->getCustomerName($customer),
            'firstname' => $customer->getFirstname(),
        ];
    }
```

As we can see, this method will check the exist of customer. And then, it will return the `fullname` and `lastname`.

Local storage:

[image]

Basicall, your script can be:

```
        isActive: function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');
            if(customer().fullname && customer().firstname)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
```

Technically, we can add a login flag to in customer data by overriding the customer data.

Comment: I saw that code, but frontend isn't sending request to server after login (account dashboard).

Comment: I'm not sure about your code, however, we can get the customer data from local storage `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')`.

Comment: You can update your full code lines of your custom module on your question.

Answer (score 2):

For Magento >2.1.* versions, if customer is logged in then we get firstname, fullname & websiteId information in mage-cache-storage.

So to retrieve customer data, use **'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'** in your JS file's require arra. Following is the sample code:

```
define([ 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        /**
         * Get customer local storage cache data
         */
        var customer = customerData.get('customer')();

        if (customer.fullname && customer.firstname)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the data may not be loaded yet. You could use this approach:

```
define([..., 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 'ko', ...], 
    function(..., customerData, 'ko', ...) {
        return Component.extend({
            ...
            /** Is login form enabled for current customer */
            isActive: ko.observable(false),
            initialize: function () {

                var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                var _self = this;
                customer.subscribe(function (data) {
                    if(data.firstname) {
                       _self.isActive(true);
                    }
                }, this);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is perfect working for me. and i think this is perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

just add this script in your phtml file and change code in your `if else`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {
            var isLoggedIn = jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
            
            if(isLoggedIn){
                
            }else{
                
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sometimes we need straight and shorten way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work with the following:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer",
    "mage/cookies"
], function ($, customer) {
    "use strict";
    return function regpopup() {
        var loggedIn = (typeof(isLoggedIn) == 'boolean') ? isLoggedIn : customer.isLoggedIn();
        var regMsgSeen = ($.mage.cookies.get('regMsgSeen') == 1);

        var isRegPage = /\/customer\/account\/create/.test(window.location.pathname);

        if(!regMsgSeen && !loggedIn && ! isRegPage) {
            $(document).ready(
                function () {
                    $.mage.cookies.set('regMsgSeen',1,{});
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            // only open register dialogue if login modal is not open
                            if($("#zoo-login-form").closest("aside").hasClass('_show') == false) {
                                $('div#zoo-register-form').modal('openModal');
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Then added the file under my theme's web/js folder, added a reference to the file in the theme's requirejs-config.js

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this at browser console and should return customer logged in or not logged in status.

```
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function ($, customerData) {
    var customer = customerData.get('customer')();
    if (customer.fullname && customer.firstname)
    {
        console.log('logged in');
    } else {
        console.log('NOT logged in');
    }             
});
```

Answer (score -4):

To check customer is logged in or not, try the below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
 {
 // Your code
 }

else
 {
 }
```

Comment: You described how to check it on server side, but my question about client side

Comment: please update with your answer, check logged in via js.