# how to get customer session id in html page magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, payment, session, object-manager

I am using one custom payment module and i want to do code in html file. Path is

`app/code/Custom/Payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/custompayment.html`

and my code is

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
  -----------code ---------
}
```

js file which i trying to do but not working

```
define(
[      
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    var getCustomerInfo = function () {
        var customer = customerData.get('customer');

        return customer();
    };

    var isLoggedIn = function (customerInfo) {
        customerInfo = customerInfo || getCustomerInfo();

        return customerInfo && customerInfo.firstname;
    };

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'XJ_Payment/payment/custompayment'
        },

        /** Returns send check to info */
        getMailingAddress: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
        },


    });
}
);
```

but i am not able to get result. i know this code is perfect work if i put on controller or model file. but still i am facing the issue which is output is after -> on second line all the code are print on frontend. i can't understand what's going on.

Can you please suggest me how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: the file name will be `custompayment.phtml` not `custompayment.html`

Comment: i  am sure it's html file actually i got response on second step payment method then all the data comes on response as a html pages.

Comment: thye are located in **pub/static** folder not in module files. magento auto generate the **html** files.

Comment: yes right but i need to put some conditions in html file so how can i put the conditions like customer is_loggedin or not.

Comment: please read the all conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default Magento, impossible to add PHP code to html template**. We can get the customer from local storage. We can read more here: [How to check that customer is logged in on frontend in Magento 2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134466/how-to-check-that-customer-is-logged-in-on-frontend-in-magento-2-1/134474#134474)

**UPDATE:**

In the return js, it should be:

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'XJ_Payment/payment/xjpayment'
    },

    var customerInfo = getCustomerInfo();

    /** Returns send check to info */
    getMailingAddress: function() {
        return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
    },
    isLoggedIn : isLoggedIn(customerInfo)
});
```

In your html template:

```
......
<!-- ko if: isLoggedIn() -->
    <span>Customer is logged</span>
<!-- /ko -->
......
```

Remember to delete static content and run again.

Comment: okay but is it possible to do in js file for set the condition customer is loggedin or not ?

Comment: Yes, please read the linked answer.

Comment: i was try but not working and you can see my code here 

define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Test_Payment/payment/testpayment'
            },

            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },

           
        });
    }
);

Comment: Please, update your question above. It's easy for us to follow your question.

Comment: last comment as per your answer in link like "How to check that customer is logged in on frontend in Magento 2.1?"  and my answer is related with this question.

Comment: You can update your question. What you're trying to do? I need to know the js to render the html template - `payment/custompayment.html`

Comment: please check it

Comment: How about the template `payment/custompayment.html` and `XJ_Payment/payment/xjpayment`?

Comment: it's custompayment.html template. instead of xjpayment

Comment: I updated my answer. Please, read carefully and check again.

Comment: when i set condition in html file then all code are displaying any another way to set the condition in html file ?

Comment: Hey guy, you should know how to debug: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html.

Comment: i know how to debug , simple when  your code put in html file then all the titles are not display there

Comment: I'm not yet test my code above, so may my code line has some bugs. You try to put `true` or `false` value and test again.

Comment: okay not an issue. can you please suggest me how can i get customer data on same  page (html page) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45133/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-kartik-asodariya).