# Know if user are logged in with Jquery

Tags: customer, custom, jquery, magento2.3.0

I'm doing a custom JS code but i wanna know if user are logged in with Jquery.

Comment: can you please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Its available frontend via customerData (private data)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

You can combine this with jquery. Something like this.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243312/70343

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code if you are done...or please check with below url which have ajax login popup.

https://www.siphor.com/add-a-login-popup-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

The references up can't help me cause i'm touching JS at checkout process. I finally solved it doing a jQuery check: if add new address button are visible in the code, then, the user are registered and configured they address.

Thanks for the help!