# Magento 2.3 How to check that customer is logged in using Js

Tags: javascript, customer-account, requirejs, magento2.3.4

I want find the whether the customer is logged in or not using Js. I got some links but it dosen't works and i not good at knockout js. Please give solution with brief explanation

Referred Link :

**[How to check that customer is logged in on frontend in Magento 2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134466/how-to-check-that-customer-is-logged-in-on-frontend-in-magento-2-1)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define(['Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], function (customer) {
        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            // Do your Logic.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Iam getting this kind of error **Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($, customer)** My code `define(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], function ($, customer) {
 console.log("Second Way");
 if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
  console.log("Second Way");
  alert("Entered");
 }
});`

Comment: This is the Error **i caught bro Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($, customer)**

Comment: Please give any Solution for this bro. The error i caught is shown in the console.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Check and let me know if the issue still there.

Comment: Yes iam getting the same thing bro **Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (customer) {
 console.log("Second Way");
 if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
  console.log("Second Way");
  alert("Entered");
 }
}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at intakeDefines (require.js:1221)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1402)
    at window.require (mixins.js:245)
    at index:49**

Comment: Are you adding JS using requirejs or direct in PHTML?

Comment: I had added in the Js file there is no requireJs in that file My file : **app\code\Vendor\My Module\view\frontend\web\js\login.js**

Comment: And how you called this JS file for your module?

Comment: I had added the in the this module layout file using **<script src="Vendor_Module::js/Login.js"></script>**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104989/discussion-between-sabareesh-and-kishor-thummar).

Answer (score 0):

```
 require(['Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], function (customer) {
        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log('Logged In');
        } else {
            console.log('Not Logged In');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You it didn't gives any error but it shows only the else part when the customer is logged in also. @Shailesh Katarmal

Answer (score -1):

```
**
 * This file will check that customer is logged in
 */
define(
    ['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'],
    function ($, customerData) {
        'use strict';

        var getCustomerInfo = function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');

            return customer();
        };

        var isLoggedIn = function (customerInfo) {
            customerInfo = customerInfo || getCustomerInfo();

            return customerInfo && customerInfo.firstname;
        };

        return function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var customerInfo = getCustomerInfo();

            if (customerInfo && customerInfo.data_id) {
                deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn(customerInfo));
            } else {
                customerData.reload(['customer'], false)
                    .done(function () {
                        console.log(isLoggedIn());
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
            }

            return deferred;
        };
    }
);
```