# How to check that customer is logged in or not using Js?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, customer

I want find the whether the customer is logged in or not using `js`. I got some links but it doesn't works and i not good at knockout `js`. Please give solution with brief explanation.

I can't get the correct answer for this and the solutions I got didn't work to me please help to find the solution.

Refered Link:[Magento 2.3 How to check that customer is logged in using Js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305456/magento-2-3-how-to-check-that-customer-is-logged-in-using-js)

Answer (score 1):

We will include a js file in theme :

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            biboo: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'], function($, customer){
   "use strict";
       return function ifCustomerIsLoggedIn()
       {
           if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
               console.info('Yes, customer is logged in');
               //your logic goes here
           } else {
               console.info('No, customer is not logged in');
               //your logic goes here
           }
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'biboo'], function($, ifCustomerIsLoggedIn) {
        ifCustomerIsLoggedIn();
    });
</script>
```

```
clean the cache

clean var/view_preprocessed content

clean pub/static content

deploy the static content = php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @prince i will check and give you the update