# how to get the value from deferred javascript function (Magento 2.4)?

Tags: javascript

I copy the js code from [How to check that customer is logged in on frontend in Magento 2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134466/how-to-check-that-customer-is-logged-in-on-frontend-in-magento-2-1/)
I have defined the js code on my javascript, but I do not how to get the return value.
How to get the return value?

```
/**
 * ****/js/check_login.js
 */
define(
    ['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'],
    function ($, customerData) {
        'use strict';

        var getCustomerInfo = function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');

            return customer();
        };

        var isLoggedIn = function (customerInfo) {
            customerInfo = customerInfo || getCustomerInfo();

            return customerInfo && customerInfo.firstname;
        };

        return function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var customerInfo = getCustomerInfo();

            if (customerInfo && customerInfo.data_id) {
                deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn(customerInfo));
            } else {
                customerData.reload(['customer'], false)
                    .done(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn());
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
            }

            return deferred;
        };
    }
);
```

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Vendor_Module/js/check_login'
], function (Component, $, modal, storage, checklogin) {
    'use strict';

    console.log(checklogin());
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get what I needed

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Vendor_Module/js/check_login'
], function (Component, $, modal, storage, checklogin) {
    'use strict';

    var getLogin = checklogin();

    // firstname is the return value from check_login.js
    getLogin.then(function(firstname){
        // you code here
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-account text-hidden" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().firstname  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
         data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Hello!, %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().firstname  -->
        <?php echo __('Hello! Sign in'); ?>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

i used to check login this way